# Getting "Object invoked has disconnected from its' client", out of options

Tags: excel, vba

So, I am trying to build a sheet that submits information in other sheets into a web form, however I keep getting the aforementioned error whenever I run it.

My code where I'm getting the error is a follows:

```
Sub SubmitForm()


Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim IE As Object


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Opens up the webpage to the screen

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "my website here... sorry, work privacy policy"


Do While IE.ReadyState = 3: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop



RowCounter = 2

' Assigning the cells to their respective boxes
Set wbPath = ActiveWorkbook
Set sh = ActiveSheet
For Each rw In sh.Rows
    IE.Document.getElementByName("baseTRICModel.rid").Value = Cells(RowCounter, 8)
    IE.Document.getElementById("baseTRICModel.actionCode").Value = Cells(RowCounter, 17)
    IE.Document.getElementById("baseTRICModel.stockNumber").Value = Cells(RowCounter, 4)
    IE.Document.getElementById("baseTRICModel.quantity").Value = Cells(RowCounter, 7)
    IE.Document.getElementById("baseTRICModel.documentNumber").Value = Cells(RowCounter, 18)
    IE.Document.getElementById("baseTRICModel.suffixCode").Value = Cells(RowCounter, 19)
    IE.Document.getElementById("baseTRICModel.suppAddress").Value = "FB4852"

    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1

    Next rw
```

I get the error at the Ready State lines, or if I just get mad and put in Application.wait, then it just goes to the next line and throws the error.

I've tried all of the solutions that are else where here, and system admin has locked the IE security settings to medium.

Any help you can provide would be amazing.. thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have `Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop` and then immediately after `Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop` ? `readystate` of `4` means "Done". So your first loop says "While IE is DONE, loop" and then your next loop says "Until IE is dONE, loop. I think maybe just remove that `Do While` loop and see if that clears up the issue.

Comment: That was specifically from one of the troubleshooting tips I saw on here.

Comment: Perhaps there is some utility to looping while IE is in `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` and then immediately after looping until IE is in `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`, but I can't imagine what sense that makes without some code in between that would cause `IE` to change states that we would want to loop waiting for `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`.

Comment: You are looping through your sheet rows here too and then picking information from certain elements from the IE page's DOM. But... in each loop you don't update the DOM. You don't press a button or cause any action that would cause the data to change. This seems like it would run once, put some data in your sheet, hang forever until it errors. I think even if you push past this error that your code isn't doing what you think it's doing. I would remove ALL `Do... ReadyState` loops in the code and just add back the `Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop` before your `For Each` loop.

Comment: I had a "click submit" line in there, however I ran into this error, and I took it out to focus on getting it to run even once.

Comment: Really you just want to have IE navigate to your web page and you want your code to wait `UNTIL` IE's `ReadyState = 4` (`READYSTATE_COMPLETE`). Then you want to execute your `for` loop, grab your values... and then click a button, and right after clicking the button then...`Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop` again. Just once, no `While`.